# Set size of elements in LazyVerticalGrid Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to set size of item in LazyVerticalGrid?
I know how to set **width** of each element:

```kotlin
LazyColumn(column = GridCells.Fixed(3)) {
  item(span = { GridItemSpan(2)) {
    //...
  }
}
```

But how to expand item`s **height**?

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: The height depends on the children's composable's height which you can set to any value easily using modifiers.

Comment: @Abhimanyu, I want to set height of 2 elements to 1 item(LazyVerticalGrid will display 1 tall item instead of 2 short)

Comment: Can you post some images? Not able to get what you are trying.